# Trying to set values in an array

Tags: python-2.7

I am not an expert on python. Following is a simple example to demonstrate my problem. First .set is accepted but the second .set that tries to set value in an array gives me error 'str' object has no attribute 'set'. And StringVar() does not seem to allow an array. Any suggestion.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Data1 = StringVar()
Data1.set("Hello1")
Data2 =[""]*3
Data2[1].set("Hello2")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.set()` is a method of `StringVar` and other special Tkinter variable types; no such method exists for Python `str`s (and no such method can exist, because one of the critical features of `str`s is that they are immutable).  There's no reason why you couldn't make a list of `StringVar`s, though: `Data2 = [StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()]` would do it, or `Data2 = [StringVar() for _ in range(3)]` to make the quantity easily adjustable.  Note that `Data2 = [StringVar()]*3` does __not__ work: that gives you a list with three references to a single `StringVar`.

Comment: Many thanks, Jasonharper. I will try this in my main program.